# No internet access to 2nd router + devices

Tags: networking, router, dns, routing, wired-networking

I do some IT work for an auto body shop. I must separate some devices onto a router and place them on a different subnet. The two subnets are **192.168.1.0/24** and **192.168.2.0/24**. No firewall has been implemented yet. I am able to communicate from the devices on the **192.168.2.0/24** to **192.168.1.0/24** and vice versa.

Since it will only be a few devices they are all assigned static IPs. I do have them pointing to the DNS server on **192.168.1.2** and can ping to it. Do I need a DNS server specially on 192.68.2.0 network? I did temporarily enable DHCP on R2 and was still able to ping to R1 but no internet.

The two devices used are TP-Link Archer C9 for the **192.168.1.0/24** (main network) and TP-Link ER605 for the other network. Before there was a switch in place of the ER605, and the devices connected to the switch got the internet fine. So, it's some setting in the ER605. Unsure of what though.

Does the WAN port matter at all for this? Those really are just for direct connection with the ISP gear I thought. Do I need to implement NAT? There is an option for one-to-one NAT, would I just change all the addressed over to **192.168.1.0/24** network?

It's also the ER605 itself that does not have access to the internet. I was unable to run ping to the internet even with DNS showing the translated IP and pings to IP addresses failed as well.

Comment: Is your DNS server actually on IP 192.168.1.0? Or are you referring to it being on the 192.168.1.0 subnet?  While it's possible to assign a .0 IP address if you are using /23 subnet setup, it's a little unusual and can lead to confusion. If you don't need to do that, it might be better to use standard /24 subnet

Comment: Yes the DNS server is 192.168.1.2. It runs off a windows server. It was set up long before for the main network. Both networks have the same subnet mask of /24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup a static route between the two routers if you want to use the ER605 as a router.

Here's an article that should help you with principles of it. https://serverfault.com/questions/882970/how-can-i-define-static-routes-between-two-subnets-in-openwrt-lede

However, static Routes can get a little tricky to configure.

If you only have a few devices and you are using static IPs, you could consider just using the ER605 to act as a switch by setting the WAN/LAN ports to LAN and link the ER605 to Router 1 via one of the LAN ports.

Comment: I do have a static route set. The one I have it the route for 192.168.1.0 network. Do I need to make a static route for something out to the internet? Not sure what address I would even use for that? Maybe my public WAN?

There was a switch inplace before but I can't use it like a switch as the devices from R2 will need to be segments from the main network via firewall. Though I do need it to have internet as one of the devices will be accessed remotely.

Comment: You could implement a NAT on the ER605, but you'll be doing a double-NAT which usually works for regular traffic, but can cause issues with certain network applications.  If not doing double-NAT, then the clients on the 192.168.2.0 subnet will need to be pointed your main router as the gateway to get to the internet.

Comment: Okay thank you I was thinking if NAT would work. Looking at the GUI for it now seems pretty straight forward.

Is that gateway seperate from the default gateway? I have not seen any option to enter a gateway for internet. If it is different I can try looking for it but I always thought the default gateway had to be the router of the network the device is a part of.

Comment: The ER605 will need the IP of the main router set as the gateway (or configure ER605 WAN to pull everything from main router via DHCP with a static lease).  If you want devices between the subnets to talk to each other you'll need to adjust subnet masks accordingly and NAT should handle the rest. If my comment or answers were at all helpful, upvotes appreciated.